# How to make nesting subscription in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

Hello I'm having a nesting subscription in my angular and i'm handling in the below way and heard it's a bad approach.

Can anyone let me know the best possible way to do? It will really help me to learn.Below is my code, please have a look. TIA

login.ts

```
 login(email: string, password: string) {
    const user = new FormData();
    user.append("username", email);
    user.append("password", password);
    this.http
      .post<any>("api1", user)
      .subscribe((response) => {
        this.myToken = response.access_token;
        console.log(this.myToken);
        if (this.myToken) {
          const body = new HttpParams()
            .set("username", email)
            .set("password", password);

          return this.http
            .post<any>("api2", body, {
              headers: new HttpHeaders({
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                Authorization: `${this.myToken}`,
              })
            })
            .subscribe((response) => console.log(response));
        } else {
          alert("error: Not authorized");
        }
      });
  }
```

2)When my component is loaded i need to check my get api response. If I get `get API` `response == null` I need to post data using the same form. When my get API `response != null`, then I need to patch the values to the form and should able to update it using `PUT API`

form.ts

```
 getVal() {
      http.get<any>(API).subscribe(response => {
       this.getResponse= response;
       if (this.getResponse != null) {
          this.form.patchValue({.     //append the values to the form
            username: response.username,
          })

      })
    }

   onRegisterSubmit(form) {
   this.username = form.value
   console.log(form.value);
    if (this.getResponse != null) {
       //I want to enable update button and update api here
          http.put<any>(api, this.username).subscribe(resposne => 
          console.log(response) )
        } if(response == null) {
           http.post<any>(api, this.username).subscribe(resposne => 
          console.log(response) )
        //I want to send data using post method.
        }
 }
```

Comment: @wentjun Yeah but i'm not clear with my second case `form.ts`. How can I map into `mergeMap` or `forkJoint`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested subscriptions are bad because there would multiple subscriptions that have no direct dependencies and would lead to more potential memory leaks. You need to use RxJS higher order operators (like [`switchMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap)) to combine multiple observables. Try the following

```js
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

login(email: string, password: string) {
  const user = new FormData();
  user.append("username", email);
  user.append("password", password);
  this.http.post<any>("api1", user).pipe(
    switchMap((response) => {
      this.myToken = response.access_token;
      console.log(this.myToken);
      if (this.myToken) {
        const body = new HttpParams().set("username", email).set("password", password);
        const headers = new HttpHeaders({
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          Authorization: `${this.myToken}`
        });
        return this.http.post<any>("api2", body, { headers: headers });
      } else {
        alert("error: Not authorized");
        return EMPTY;
      }
    })
  ).subscribe(
    (response) => { console.log(response) },
    (error) => { }
  );
}
```

#### Update - wrong

In the `onRegisterSubmit()` function, we check if the `this.getResponse` variable is defined already, but it is assigned a value asynchronously in the `getVal()` function.

```js
onRegisterSubmit(form) {
  this.username = form.value;
  console.log(form.value);
  if (this.getResponse) {         // <-- implies `this.getResponse` is already assigned in `onRegisterSubmit()` function
    http.put<any>(api, this.username).pipe(
      switchMap(putResponse => {
        console.log(putResponse);
        if(!putResponse) {
          return http.post<any>(api, this.username);
        }
        return EMPTY;
      })
    ).subscribe(
      postResponse => { console.log(Postresponse) },
      error => { }
    );
  }
}
```

The `switchMap()` operator should return an observable. So if we have no observable to return, we could use RxJS [`EMPTY`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/const/EMPTY) constant.  It creates an observable that immediately emits the complete notification.

#### Update 2

To conditionally subscribe to an observable, you could use RxJS [`iif`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/iif) method.

```js
onRegisterSubmit(form) {
  this.username = form.value;
  console.log(form.value);
  iif(() => 
    this.getResponse,
    http.put<any>(api, this.username),
    http.post<any>(api, this.username)
  ).subscribe(
    respone => { console.log(response) },
    error => { }
  );
}
```

Comment: So instead of subscribing we use `switchmap` to stores the response of first req and will be assigned to next call. Finally the subscription is done in complete level ?

Comment: If apply `switchMap` for my `form.ts` I'm not able to perform operation.

Comment: And what's the use of `EMPTY` ?

Comment: Yes the subscription is done on the final observable returned from the `switchMap` operator. I've updated the answer.

Comment: last doubt.  `getResponse` will have `value` or `null` . If it has value it should go to put. if it's null it should go to post. Here everything is wrapped in if(getResponse). How can it handle? There will be always put response, then when will it get in to post response?

Comment: In that case I misunderstood your question and made the POST request dependent on the PUT request. I've update the answer to conditionally select PUT or POST request based on the `this.getResponse` variable.

Comment: Updated my question .Please have a look

Comment: @sai: I believe the 2nd update should solve the issue.

Comment: How can it understand like to which method the call should go? Do I need to write if statement for checking the value is null or has some value? Or is there anything like `if ==true` call first method `if==false` call second method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215456/discussion-between-michael-d-and-sai).

Answer (score 0):

In your last doubt. You need not to wrap around `Put` as `this.getResponse` is the value not observable so its better to use `if and else` condition than using any Rxjs Operator. As using `if and else` is not the nested subscription for `onRegisterSubmit method`.

or you can use it like

```
onRegisterSubmit(form) {
 this.username = form.value;
  iif(() => 
    this.getResponse,
    http.put<any>(api, this.username),
    http.post<any>(api, this.username)
  ).subscribe(
    respone => { console.log(response) },
    error => { }
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you post the answer with explanation?

Comment: [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-iif?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100) in the given example you can see that it works on `Subscribe to first or second observable based on a condition`. So in your case if `this.getResponse` will be not null than `put `call will be made and subscribed otherwise `Post` call will be made and subscribed. I believe that is your intent.

Comment: Tnd the above solution is using RXJS only, right? And my in my case  `get` should be init on ngOnInit and remaining two calls will be executed on submit button

Comment: I got the above solution from @ Michael D
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62241971/10928596)